# How to performe command in multiple servers through ssh?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, ssh, centos

I'm trying to execute command on multiple servers through ssh, that's what I'm trying to do:

```
for i in {1..3}; do `ssh nginx_$i ps aux | grep logstash`; done
```

But it tells me to install some package:

```
The program 'root' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install root-system-bin
```

I'm not convinced that I need to install it, because if I do

```
ssh nginx_1 ps aux | grep logstash
```

It works, and gives me the correct result.

P.S. Assuming that I have configured `.ssh/config` file to connect to `nginx_1`, `nginx_2` and `nginx_3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> for i in {1..3}; do `ssh nginx_$i ps aux | grep logstash`; done
>                     ^                                   ^
> ```

Drop the backquotes. If you include them, the shell will try to execute the output of the command.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the for loop you should use [pssh](https://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/).